# Install Neo4j 4.2.1 on SUSE SLES12

Tags: installation, sles, neo4j

I´m currently running neo4j 3.5.11 on a SUSE SLES 12 SP5 and I want to Upgrade to Version 4.2.1.

Official Docs (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.2/installation/linux/rpm/#linux-rpm-suse) tell me to install at least Java 11 runtime. So I did this with:

**$ zypper install java-11-openjdk**

After this I already changed the Link of /usr/bin/java with:

**$ sudo update-alternatives --config java**

To the new Version and

**$ java -version**

Shows:

```
openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-suse-3.15.1-x8664)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-suse-3.15.1-x8664, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to start:

**$ neo4j console**

I only get:

```
ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_272.
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 11, OpenJDK(TM) 11 to run Neo4j.
* Please see https://neo4j.com/docs/ for Neo4j installation instructions.
```

This is my old java version.
What am I missing???

P.S. I already rebooted the System.

Comment: Did you try removing the old Java version?

Comment: No, I dont want to ruin my currently perfectly working Neo4J V3.5.11 installation.

Comment: So you're trying to run both versions of Neo4J?

Comment: Thats what im trying to do. Run the old Version until the next Version is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this: https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-update-alternative.html

helped me fixing the issue.

/usr/bin/java was directed to an old/ non supported version.